# Need help finding a SAS HBA controller for an IBM LTO 4 Tape Drive

Tags: storage, tape, sas, hba, ibm-xseries

I've got an older IBM x3200 M2 Server (MT: 4368) and I recently acquired a used internal IBM LTO 4 tape drive ([FRU: 45E1125](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?brand=5000008&lndocid=MIGR-5074627)).  The back of the tape drive requires an Internal SAS 29 pin connector ([SFF-8482](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBr9h.jpg)) .

I'm trying to purchase a PCIe SAS HBA that will allow me to utilize this internal tape drive and I'm having issues.  I tried an Adaptec 1405 but the Server refused to move beyond POST with it installed.  After talking with IBM support, they directed me to the ["Server Proven"](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/info/x86servers/serverproven/compat/us/tape/44E8895.html) page which identified this [46M0907 SAS HBA](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/tips0776.html) as a proven working controller.  However, when I received it, it had an external SFF-8088 external SAS connector and 4 internal connectors that appeared to be SATA.  This seems to be different than the documentation which lists 4 x1 SFF-8087 ports.

I've typically seen SFF-8087 look like [This](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SFF_8087.jpg).  However, the ports on the card did not look like that.  They looked like standard [SATA ports](http://www.dcparts.com/images/Sata-red-3.gif).

I found pictures on the web of cables that looked like they went from a [SATA style port to SFF-8482](http://img356.imageshack.us/img356/503/sas82821sz9.jpg).

First, am I taking crazy pills?  Is it that simple?  Do I just need to adapt from a SATA connector to a SFF-8482?  Is it possible their documentation is wrong?  Can someone make a recommendation or shed some light on this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the right cable. Any 7-Pin SAS to SFF8482 should work. IBM Probably sells one for $100, or you can [find them on the net fairly cheap](http://www.pc-pitstop.com/sas_cables_adapters/I2917-05M.asp).

Comment: I tried ordering the cable and I'll give it a shot.  I'm frankly surprised that the manufacturer and the vendor seem so perplexed by the question.  The worst is the conflicting information in the documentation!  I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: I tried the cable yesterday and it worked.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Use an LSI controller for the internal LTO drive.

http://www.lsi.com/channel/products/hba/sas_sata_hbas/internal/lsisas3041er/index.html

Power is provided to the drive via the Molex connector. Use the adaptor cables.